# Date returning from c# web method - /Date(xxxxxxx)/

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, date, webmethod

I am using jquery ajax to request a list of objects from a database via a c# web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<SessionQueue> GetActiveIssues()
{           
  try
  {
    return MyContext.SessionQueues.Where(x => !x.Resolved).OrderBy(d => d.SubmittedTime).ToList();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.ToString()); // catch in jquery
  }
```

}

Each `SessionQueue` object has a property:

```
public System.DateTime SubmittedTime
```

When I receive the SubmittedTime in jquery, the date looks like this:

```
/Date(1445975227197)/
```

How do I parse this to a valid date string? e.e `mm/dd/yy xx:xx am`

I have tried:

```
function formatLongDate(date) {

    var nd = Date.parse(date);
    var dt = new Date(nd);
    var dtStr = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", dt) + ' ' + getTime(date)
    return dtStr;
}
```

but `/Date(1445975227197)/` is not a valid date ticks

Comment: It's the number of ticks since Jan 1, 1970 I believe.

Comment: Use moment.js. I had similar situation and momentjs help me a lot.

Comment: Or switch to using JSON.NET 4.5+ as the serializer  which defaults to formatting dates in ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` , `Array.protottpe.map()`

```
new Date("/Date(1445975227197)/".match(/\d+/).map(Number)[0])
```

Comment: How to get the output in a format like "Oct 28 2015" ?

Comment: @Arun `String(new Date("/Date(1445975227197)/".match(/\d+/).map(Number)[0])).slice(4, 15)`

Comment: Thanks @guest271314

Answer (score 1):

MVC Converts dates to the number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.  The simplest way to convert it to a javascript date is to do the following

```
var convertedDate = new Date(parseInt(SubmittedTime.substr(6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//timestamp is where you're getting the 1445975227197
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);

int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```